# Adware no meu projeto

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Bom dia,

tenho um projeto no Visual Studio 2013 utilizando Entity Framework, até aí tudo bem, mas de uma hora pra outra quando fui executá-lo apareceu Ads(Propagandas) nele, uns quadrados com vários ads, mas sem imagens das propagandas e outras com imagens. Isso acontece em dois navegadores (firefox e google chrome), quando navego normal não aparece nenhum ad. Porém se inicio o projeto com um navegador e jogo o link do meu projeto em outro navegador os ads desaparecem.

Será que peguei algum Adware? O que devo fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual tipo de projeto você está usando? É WEB? Como está executando?

Comment: Se possível, poste fotos e mais detalhes.

Comment: é um projeto para a web, com um servidor local por enquanto, mas estou fazendo tudo no meu pc.

Comment: Tente acessar por outro navegador. Seu navegador provavelmente é que está com alguma extensão ou outra coisa.

Comment: Eu ja tentei, tentei no firefox e no chrome e estão a mesma coisa.

Comment: O que exatamente aparece? Muitos contaminam todos os browsers... Recomendo usar ferramentas de limpeza, spybot, cclean, etc.

Comment: como faço para por uma imagem?

Comment: Poste o código rapaz

Comment: Qual código você precisa? Pois não coloquei nada de mais para ficar assim. Isso aconteceu de uma hora pra outra.

Answer (score 1):

O Visual Studio não mostra propagandas ou coisas do tipo em seus projetos, logo é problema no seu PC. Sugiro que rode um Spybot e revise as extensões instaladas no seu Browser.

Se você andou instalando algum programa nos últimos dias, acrescento que alguns  costumam instalar "barrinhas" nos navegadores, essas barrinhas são uma praga e costumam fazer esse tipo de coisa. Sugiro que sempre leia o wizard e saiba exatamente o que o programa vai instalar, pois geralmente a instalação da "barrinha" é opcional. Evite também baixar programas em sites tipo Baixaki, superdownloads, etc...

Comment: Somente aparece no meu projeto, tanto no google chrome, como no firefox. Quando estou navegando normalmente não aparece nada.

Comment: Por favor, bota um screenshot então.

Comment: como faço isso?

Comment: Edgar não está claro o meu problema? O que faço para ser mais preciso?

Comment: Sinceramente não está claro. Além disso sua pergunta não é sobre programação. Sugiro que edite sua pergunta e coloque uma foto desses adwares (use o help se não souber fazer) e, se for viável, coloque o trecho de código que você acha que pode estar causando o problema. Agora o que eu sei é que o Visual Studio não faz esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Olhando suas imagens eu vi o problema. Sinceramente é impossível alguém aqui te dar uma solução. Vou e instalou algum addon de terceiros no visual Studio?

Comment: Não instalei e não coloquei nenhum código a mais para ocorrer isso, eu fiz uma pergunta no site de suporte do vs, estou aguardando. Não sei se vão me ajudar e não sei onde procurar ajuda, estou desesperado. Na pior das hipóteses vou formatar meu computador.

Comment: Rapaz, se o projeto está conforme wizard então é melhor VC formatar sua máquina. Eu não creio que esses ads fazem parte do projeto.

Comment: @jp_almeida se puder corra o projecto noutra maquina ou entao configure a sua maquina para que possa aceder com o browser de outro computador ou mesmo com PowerShell, faca um GET da sua URL e veja no HTML devolvido se la esta algum tipo de propaganda.

Comment: Eu consegui tirar os ads através de um programa que retira ads. Somente aparecia no navegador que eu rodei meu projeto, outro aberto em que eu colava meu link funcionou sem os ads, normalmente. A todos obrigado pela ajuda.